# Is there a way to make Android Studio 3.5 remember target device selection?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.5

I frequently run my apps on multiple devices at once. Before the 3.5 update, I was able to do this by cmd-clicking them in the device selection window and checking "use the same selection for future launches". 3.5 introduced this new dropdown in the toolbar to replace that window. Not only does it now try running your app on an emulator if you run it before adb recognizes your device, it doesn't remember *anything at all*. There is an option to "Run on multiple devices", but you have to select devices every time. This is just so laughably worse than what was before.

Can I either bring back the old device selector or make the new one remember my selection?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to get Android Studio 3.5 to *remember* which devices to run but there's a plugin that I use to accomplish this: [ADB Idea](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7380-adb-idea/versions): `Preferences/Settings -> Plugins -> Marketplace`.

It has an option to start the app with a checkbox for remembering.

[image]

Once you install it, you access it in `Tools` or use a keyboard shortcut: `Ctrl+Shift+A` on Mac & `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+A` on Windows/Linux

[image]